# using Array.prototype.map to insert object with index into 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, functional-programming

For context, this is for the classic battleships game.

I have a gameboard grid array like so:

```
[[null, null, null, null, null],
[null, null, null, null, null],
[null, null, null, null, null],
[null, null, null, null, null],
[null, null, null, null, null]],
```

I'm attempting to place a `ship` object in the array. The object consists of some properties, such as the ship's `name`, it's `length` and it's `index` (so that the position the ship is hit can be marked on the ship object). For example, a ship placed on the first row might look like this:

`[null, {name: 'boat' , index: 0 }, {name: 'boat' , index: 1 }, null, null]`

I want to achieve this using functional programming principles and avoid mutating the array, which is what I'm currently doing (i.e. using for loops and setting `array[x][y] = {ship}`).

I understand that the best way of achieving this is by using `map()`.

Since the array is 2 dimensional I am nesting two maps together. My function so far looks like this:

```
const placeShip = (ship, x, y) => {
    if (grid[x][y] !== null) return;
    const newGrid = grid.map((row, indexX) => row.map((element, indexY) => {
      if (indexX === x && indexY === y) {
        {
          name: ship.name,
          index: XXX
        } // how to insert the index position?
      }
    }
    return newGrid
  }
```

The trouble I am experiencing is twofold. Firstly, I can't figure out how I can correctly insert the ship's index position in the object using the nested map. This was easy enough using `for` loops as they begin at `0` and end at `ship.length`.

Secondly, I'm going wrong somewhere and my function is not returning a 2d array with any objects in it, I am just receiving `undefined`.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `return`. That's all.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I think I've been staring at this for too long

Comment: When you say `how to insert the index position?` it's not clear what index you are referring to. What should that value be? A single number? a array with x, y coords?

Comment: @LearningPython you aren't returning anything from your inner row .map, so you are going to wind up with a grid of `undefined`s. Which is also going to cause your conditional check at the beginning to have false positives on subsequent calls.

Comment: @Mark I am trying to include the index position of the ship's length. Maybe it wasn't clear in the example I give towards the start of my question. Basically, when a hit is placed on the grid and it hits a ship, I need to record on the ship object which position of the ship was hit. E.g. if it was 4 cells long, whether it was hit in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th part of its length. Does that make sense?

Comment: @LearningPython you don't have anything in your question that would indicate you needed that, and your code is riddled with issues like the ones I already described.

Comment: Copied and pasted from the start of my question:  The object consists of some properties, such as the ship's `name`, it's `length` and it's `index` (so that the position the ship is hit can be marked on the ship object). For example, a ship placed on the first row might look like this:

`[null, {name: 'boat' , index: 0 }, {name: 'boat' , index: 1 }, null, null]`

Comment: (and it's in the question title!) :)

Comment: You're missing the `)` at the end of the `map(` function.

Comment: If you want to include the index Value from your object, then its simply, ````{name: ship.name, index: ship.index }````, but if you want to include index of the actual position in the array, you can do ````{name: ship.name, index: grid.indexOf(grid[x][y])}````. I hope am not too far away from what you want

Comment: `index: indexX`

Comment: `{ name: ship.name, index: XXX }` needs to be in a `return` statement, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only consider horizontally placed ships, you can check whether a ship appears on a tile like so:

```
ri === r &&    // The ship sails on the current row
ci >= c &&     // The start of the ship lies left of this column
ci < c + size  // The end of the ship lies right of this column
```

Then, the index between `0` and `shipSize` can be calculated using: `ci - c`

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const grid = Array.from(Array(4), () => Array(4).fill("~~"));

const placeShipH = (r, c, size, name, grid) => grid.map(
  (row, ri) => row.map(
    (col, ci) => ri === r && ci >= c && ci < c + size
      ? `${name}${ci - c + 1}`
      : col
  )
);

const placeShipV = (r, c, size, name, grid) => grid.map(
  (row, ri) => row.map(
    (col, ci) => ci === c && ri >= r && ri < r + size
      ? `${name}${ri - r + 1}`
      : col
  )
);

const gridToString = grid => grid.map(row => row.join(" ")).join("\n");

const afterShipA = placeShipH(1, 1, 2, "A", grid);
const afterShipB = placeShipH(3, 0, 3, "B", afterShipA);
const afterShipC = placeShipV(0, 3, 3, "C", afterShipB)

console.log(gridToString(afterShipC));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to adapt it for vertical layouts too, which I imagine shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I spoke too soon I think. Are there any considerable changes to the above in order to implement for vertical placement? I'm using `(columnIndex === column && rowIndex >= row && rowIndex < row + ship.length)` however I seem to be getting infinitely long column ships.

Comment: The code you've shown looks good to me... I added the vertical example in the example above and it seems to work. Maybe the `.length` property is undefined?